# Pay Later option missing on front end CiviCRM 4.7.10

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, paypal, paylater, 4.7.10

CiviCRM 4.7.10

Joomla! 3.6.2

Payment gateway: PayPal Standard

I see this issue was reported earlier on Civicrm 4.7.8, but the bug report https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18118 says fixed/closed

This site was running civicrm 4.6 and upgraded to 4.7 followin this process https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Joomla. In 4.6 the pay-later option was working. After upgrading to 4.7.10 pay-layer option does not show on the front end.

Below is my test event setup and the second page from the front end registration process. When I click the Continue button I'm sent to PayPal.

So, maybe I missed something in the upgrade process?
Or maybe civicrm-4.7.10-joomla.zip is missing the patch?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Joomla: 3.6.6
CiviCRM: 4.7.16 Apparently a REGRESSION has crept into the Contribution pages code. As it was fixed after 4.7.9, but I haven't checked since. Now I'm on 4.7.16 and the Pay Later option is missing from my Contribution membership signup/renewal pages as seen below. I have not tried setting up an event payment page since my last event in August, but I suspect the issue is there as shown by the screen captures entered above. [![Membership Page not showing pay later option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fva3S.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fva3S.jpg)

Comment: Pay Later is still missing in Civi 4.7.27. Missing also in Events. (Note: On Joomla 3.8.3)

Comment: I have this issue on a site running 4.7.31 too :( commenting also so I can get updates...

Comment: Having the same issue on 5.3.1…

Comment: I have the same problem with Membership Contribution. Joomla 3.8.11, CiviCRM 5.3.2, PayPal Standard.